# jq if value match then update end

Tags: json, if-statement, jq

For this data
https://jqplay.org/s/onlU9ghjn1

I can not figure out the correct syntax to do something like

```
.gcp_price_list | ."CP-COMPUTEENGINE-OS" | 
(
    if ( .[].cores == "shared" ) then
        .[].cores = 0.5 
    end
)
```

Seems I need the `else` part but I'm not sure what to put there. If I do:

```
.gcp_price_list | ."CP-COMPUTEENGINE-OS" | 
(
    if ( .[].cores == "shared" ) then
        .[].cores = 0.5 
    else .[].cores = .[].cores end
)
```

There is still "shared" in the result, i.e.

```
  "win": {
    "low": 0.02,
    "high": 0.04,
    "cores": "shared",
    "percore": true
  }
```

Inputs get replicated into the result, which is not what I want.

Related, but I don't find them very helpful, questions

[JQ If then Else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572755/jq-if-then-else)

[How do I update a single value in a json document using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034746/how-do-i-update-a-single-value-in-a-json-document-using-jq)

---

My practical alternative is "replaced all" with a text editor,
but I will leave this question here in case there is an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you want:

```
.gcp_price_list
| ."CP-COMPUTEENGINE-OS"
| map_values(
    if .cores == "shared" 
    then .cores = 0.5 
    else . end )
```

In any case, be careful when using expressions such as `.[].cores` as arguments of `if`, `then`, or `else`, because they produce a stream of results.

In future, please follow the [MCVE](/help/mcve) guidelines.

## Postscript

If you want to edit the JSON document, you would use `|=` like so:

```
.gcp_price_list."CP-COMPUTEENGINE-OS" |= 
  map_values(
    if ( .cores == "shared" ) then
        .cores = 0.5 
    else . end
  )
```