# How can I add a variable to all items of an existing JSON array?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON-array from a json-file:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Ley1",
    "file": "Filepath1",
    "line": 10,
    "rule": "csharpsquid:S1643",
    "message": "Use a StringBuilder instead.",
    "type": "CODE_SMELL"
  },
  {
    "key": "Key2",
    "file": "FilePath2",
    "line": 12,
    "rule": "csharpsquid:S1643",
    "message": "Use a StringBuilder instead.",
    "type": "CODE_SMELL"
  }
]
```

and I want to add the variable "critical" to all items of it using a bash-command so it looks like this:

```
[
      {
        "key": "Key1",
        "file": "Filepath1",
        "line": 10,
        "rule": "csharpsquid:S1643",
        "message": "Use a StringBuilder instead.",
        "type": "CODE_SMELL",
        "critical": "No"
      },
      {
        "key": "Key2",
        "file": "FilePath2",
        "line": 12,
        "rule": "csharpsquid:S1643",
        "message": "Use a StringBuilder instead.",
        "type": "CODE_SMELL",
        "critical": "Yes"
      }
    ]
```

Unfortunately I am a complete JSON and bash beginner and could not find a bash-command solving this problem. I tried a litte bit with jq on jq-play but it did not really lead to something so I wanted to try it here. I hope this are all information needed, so does anyone know maybe a command for this?

EDIT:
This here worked, thanks!

```
.[] |= . + {"critical": "No"}
```

But no i want to determine the value of "yes" or "no" depending on the file-value. Do you know how to edit the command so it checks the file-value in order to determine the critical-value?

It should decide like this:

Filepath1, Filepath3 leads to `"critical" : "No"`

and

Filepath2, Filepath4, Filepath5 leads to `"critical" : "Yes"`

Comment: How is the value of Yes or No determined? Also please post the attempts made

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add new element to existing JSON array with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245288/add-new-element-to-existing-json-array-with-jq)

Comment: `.[] |= . + {"critical": "No"}`

Comment: Unfortunatles the question of the "Add new element to existing JSON array with jq
" was about adding an item to an array, not a variable to the entries of an array

The value of yes or no depends on which filepath it is. So in filepath1, it should be no and in filepath 2 yes but since i only have like five paths available I would just want to check what the path value is and if it is from 1,2,3,4 or 5 and then if it is critical or not.

Comment: @puffel: Your claim seems to contradicting, you said `filepath1` should be no, but later said if the path is `1,2,3,4 or 5`, then critical yes ?

Comment: oh sorry! this was confusing.
Filepath1 or Filepath3 -> critical: no
Filepath2 or Filepath 4 or Filepath5 -> critical: yes

Comment: Thank you all so much, it finally works!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [jq if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572755/jq-if-then-else);

```
jq '.[] |= . + {"critical": (if .file == "FilePath1" or .file == "FilePath3" then "no" else "yes" end)}'
```

[Try it on jqPlay](https://jqplay.org/s/Ax3vVA5_-b)

Answer (score 0):

To minimize redundancy, you could go with:

```
map(. + {critical: (if .file | IN("FilePath1", "FilePath3") then "no" else "yes" end) })
```

Or for brevity:

```
map(. + {critical: ((.file | select(IN("FilePath1", "FilePath3")) | "no") // "yes" )})
```